# O que são códigos corretores de erros?

Tags: matemática, serialização, recuperação-de-erros, codificação-de-conteúdo

O que são e como funcionam os **códigos corretores de erros** ([*error-correcting code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#Error-correcting_code))? Já vi esse conceito por exemplo no [QR Code](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_QR#Corre.C3.A7.C3.A3o_de_erros) (em que um código parcialmente danificado e/ou imperfeitamente capturado ainda é legível) e também ouvi dizer que são usados em sondas espaciais, ao transmitir dados em longas distâncias com bastante interferência no sinal. Gostaria de saber mais sobre o conceito, e como/onde aplicá-lo:

(Esclarecimento: me refiro somente aos códigos, não a protocolos completos. A exemplo do QR Code, uma vez impresso ele não pode ser "reenviado", de modo que qualquer capacidade de correção precisa estar presente no código em si.)

- Quais os princípios por trás da técnica? Se for algo muito extenso, fico satisfeito com apenas uma introdução seguida de algumas referências.
- Quais as limitações? Voltando ao exemplo do QR Code, vi que é possível configurá-lo para tolerar até 30% de erro. Há algum ponto a partir do qual os códigos se tornam excessivamente longos (tendendo pro infinito, é claro[1]), qual a melhor taxa que se pode esperar na prática? E esses códigos corrigem erros em posições arbitrárias nos dados (ex.: início, meio, fim, 1 bit a cada 8, qualquer combinação das anteriores, etc) ou só alguns tipos de erro específicos? É possível o código "corrigir" pra algo diferente dos dados originais?
- Em que cenários isso é usado na prática? Existem bibliotecas prontas pra fazer isso, ou é preciso implementar à mão, caso a caso (dependendo das particularidades de cada aplicação)?

  - Esclarecendo: não estou pedindo uma "lista de casos", apenas saber em linhas gerais se vale a pena usar esse tipo de coisa no dia-a-dia, ou só em circunstâncias excepcionais (noto que na prática se é erro de comunicação, retransmite, se é erro de armazenamento, usa-se *backups*; não vejo esse tipo de coisa sendo muito discutido, nem mesmo mencionado).

Obs.: já estou familiarizado com códigos *detectores* de erros (como paridade, *checksums*, *hashes*, MACs, etc), estou interessado em códigos que permitam recuperar os dados originais mesmo na presença de algum grau de erro nos mesmos. Naturalmente, para se corrigir um erro primeiro é preciso detectá-lo, mas meu senso comum diz que os mecanismos tradicionais citados acima não são suficientes - afinal, a própria *tag* de verificação também pode ser transmitida com erros...

---

[1]: Quando digo "tendendo pro infinito" me refiro ao fato de que é impossível se corrigir um código 100% errado, a menos que ele seja infinito. Minha dúvida é se ao aumentar o nível de tolerância a erros, se o tamanho do código cresce a uma taxa elevada (ex.: quadrática, exponencial...) ou a uma taxa mais baixa (ex.: linear, logarítmica) - permitindo por exemplo atingir tolerâncias de 90% ou mais.

Comment: Já conseguiu esclarecer sua dúvida?

Comment: @drmcarvalho Já faz um tempo que fiz essa pergunta, e acabei me esquecendo do assunto hehe! Na verdade já tive algum contato com a parte teórica (embora continue com certa dificuldade de entendê-la), mas estou completamente perdido com a parte prática. Vou dar um "bump" na pergunta, de repente alguém que manja mais do assunto se manifesta...

Comment: Eu escrevi meu próprio codificador de QR, mas dava vontade de chorar ao ler a documentação. Para a parte polinomial eu fui cortando caminho em tudo quanto é lugar que deu (usando tabelas pré calculadas, e simplificando em alguns casos com array para indexar as potências). Eu sabia que eles tinham complicado na geração para simplificar a leitura, mas exageraram :) - Espero que alguém trate do assunto nas respostas, agora que tem o _bounty_, pois apesar de ser um treco chato de implementar, é bem rico em detalhes.

Comment: Sobre a última pergunta, em geral essas técnicas são usadas quando o canal de comunicação é ruidoso (ondas de rádio, imagens de código de barra, etc). Para canais não ruidosos (como uma conexão de rede) normalmente não tem problema fazer um checksum simples e reenviar os dados se tiver problema. BTW a página da wkipédia sobre [Forward Error Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) tem mais detalhes do que a que está linkada na pergunta.

Comment: MelGibsonbr, kkk, o Computer Network do Tanenbaum, aborda esse assunto no cap 3, se é que entendi bem  sua pergunta...É bem interessante, mas não estou apto a explicar... Aliás, vou ficar ligadão, pra ver se alguém se habilita, pq é mais matemática binária do que código de alto nível... Dá pra fazer uma idéia-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: @MagicHat CRC é bem mais simples, é mais para conferência dos dados. Error-correction em geral tem redundância de informação, pois o objetivo é você conseguir recuperar 100% da informação original sem retransmissão, mesmo perdendo parte dos dados.

Comment: @Bacco CRCs are based on the theory of cyclic error-correcting codes, isto posto, imagino que para se aprofundar em algo tão complexo, é necessário uma base... Mas no livro que citei aborda, outros termos também... Inclusive a recuperação dos dados ... Vale a pena dar uma, "fuçada"...

Comment: @mgibsonbr é uma pergunta boa, porém não manjo do assunto para dar uma resposta, mais vou esperar alguém responder, isso com certeza vai ajudar muito a comunidade.

Comment: @mgibsonbr vou tentar, faz um 10 ai....Trilha sonora necessária... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSAsI5pnAbc

Comment: Eis uma pergunta muito bacana. :) Ansioso pra ver o desenrolar. Enquanto isso, na sala de justiça: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KA8hDldvfv0

Comment: Peri vou precisar mais um tempinho.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jyTinxcKDg

Comment: @mgibsonbr espero que você ou qualquer outro usuário não tenha interpretado o "kkk" do meu 1º comentário, como sendo sarcástico a sua pergunta... Na verdade estou rindo do seu nick Mel Gibson BR ! x)

Comment: @MagicHat É engraçado que o dito cujo é provavelmente a razão do meu nick - mas não da maneira que parece! Quando criei meu e-mail no yahoo.com.br (sim, sou velho rsrs) queria "gibson", como meus amigos me chamam, mas já estava usado, então pus "mgibson". Quando troquei pro gmail.com, esse também já estava usado, então sem pensar muito (afinal quando é que esse tal de "Google" vai superar o todo-poderoso Yahoo?) passei o "br" que não tinha no domínio pro username. Agora que todo mundo me conhece assim, fiquei "amaldiçoado" com esse nick bizarro pro resto da vida! :P

Comment: @mgibsonbr heheh...faz parte, mas o dito cujo é legal, demonstra perspicácia, agilidade, não se sinta amaldiçoado.....kkkk

Answer (score 14):

**¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

### Detecção e correção de erro (Error detection and correction)

- *O que são e como funcionam os códigos corretores de erros ?*

***Definição***

São técnicas que permitem a entrega de dados de modo mais confiável através dos canais de comunicação.

***Introdução***

Detecção e Correção, são termos que caminham juntos sendo impossível a aplicação do segundo sem a eficácia do primeiro.

Os canais de comunicação no nível físico de modo geral são suscetíveis a sensíveis falhas, causando muitas vezes a perda ou fragmentação de dados.

***"Funcionamento, quais os princípios por trás da técnica, é possível o código "corrigir" pra algo diferente dos dados originais ?"***

Existem 2 métodos mais conhecidos para correção de erros:

1. Solicitação de repetição
   automática (ARQ - Automatic repeat request):

   Utiliza "acknowledgements" (confirmações através de mensagens enviadas pelo receptor indicando que recebeu corretamente um quadro de dados ou pacote )
   e "timesout" (períodos de tempo que antecedem uma confirmação de recebimento) de modo a realizar uma transmissão de dados confiável. Caso o emissor não receba uma confirmação do receptor antes que o "timeout" complete seu ciclo, o pacote é retransmitido até a origem receber uma confirmação ou ultrapassar um número pré-definido de tentativas.

***acknowledgements***

[image: ACK]

***timeout***

[image: Timeout]

Existem 3 protocolos principais que utilizam o método ARQ.

- [Stop-and-wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-and-wait_ARQ)
- [Go-Back-N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-Back-N_ARQ)
- [Selective Repeat ARQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Repeat_ARQ)

*Todos tem  base no [Sliding window protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol).*

2- O segundo método é o Forward error correction (Avançado corretor de
    erro):

O remetente codifica o código de forma redundante usando um código de correção de erros(ECC), através da redundância adicionada ao código o receptor recupera os dados originais, em geral **os dados reconstruídos são considerados
"os mais prováveis" dados originais**.
A base para esse método, são os trabalhos de [Richar Hamming](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hamming), autor do [código de Hamming](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_Hamming) e  [código Hamming(7,4)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_(7,4)).

Os 2 principais métodos (ARQ e FEC) quando combinados corrigem pequenos erros e evitam a retransmissão e os principais erros
são corrigidos através de 1 pedido de retransmissão : esse processo é chamado de  (HARQ) hybrid automatic repeat request.

Os principais princípios que fazem parte da base para a aplicação são:

- [o conjunto de códigos Reed-Solomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction)
- [código  BCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code)
- [MDPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_parity-check_code)
- [Algoritmo de Euclides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) e sua extensão [Algoritmo de Euclides estendido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)
- entre outros.

A explicação da lógica utilizada vai além do escopo dessa resposta, mas verificando os links, ou fazendo uma pesquisa aprofundada sobre as nomeações acima pode-se encontrar o total esclarecimento do funcionamento.

- *"Quais as limitações, qual a melhor taxa que se pode esperar na prática?"*

Hoje em dia, devido ao avanço na confecção dos meios físicos, a tolerância em alguns meios é perto de 0 (fibra ótica), e pode ser conquistado 
em alguns laboratórios especiais. No entanto a diversidade de meios, nos faz considerar por exemplo as transmissões via rádio
que dependem de um ambiente controlado, o que não é possível no dia dia, pois chuvas, ventos, topologia e outros detalhes naturais ou não, interferem
diretamente na comunicação.
**Para quadros codificados pelo CCSDS código Reed-Solomon , menos de 1 em 40.000 quadros errados podem escapar da detecção.**

- *"Há algum ponto a partir do qual os códigos se tornam excessivamente

  longos (tendendo pro infinito, é claro)?"*

Em tese, a teoria do algorítimo, afirma ser uma sequência ***finita*** de instruções. Os algorítimos de detecção e correção, são relativamente curtos, pois atuam sobre partes de tamanho definido (pacotes). No entanto, essa asserção é aplicada aos meios comerciais simples, e levando em consideração a criptografia militar, sondas espaciais e outras aplicações, creio que realmente podem tender pro "infinito", ou algumas milhões de linhas...  Apesar que o uso da lógica serve exatamente para inibir está ideia, eu acho...

- *"E esses códigos corrigem erros em posições arbitrárias nos dados
  (ex.: início, meio, fim, 1 bit a cada 8, qualquer combinação das
  anteriores, etc) ou só alguns tipos de erro específicos?"*

Eles atuam sobre partes pré-determinadas dos pacotes, ou seja, sim, a arbitrariedade no caso não é o começo, meio ou fim, mas o erro detectado em si.

O Comité Consultivo para Sistemas Espaciais de Dados ( CCSDS ) define o protocolo utilizado para a transmissão de dados de instrumentos de nave espacial através do canal do espaço profundo. Segundo este padrão, uma imagem ou outros dados enviados a partir de um instrumento de nave espacial é transmitida utilizando um ou mais pacotes, variando de 7 a 65.542 bytes, incluindo o cabeçalho do pacote. Esses por sua vez são transmitidos através de quadros de até 2048 bytes.

- *"Em que cenários isso é usado na prática?"*

  - Internet
  - Telecomunicações no espaço profundo
  - Radiodifusão via satélite
  - Armazenamento de dados
  - Memória com correção de erro
- *"Existem bibliotecas prontas pra fazer isso, ou é preciso implementar
  à mão, caso a caso (dependendo das particularidades de cada aplicação)?"*

O conjunto de códigos e protocolos utilizados para a construção de progrmas direcionados a essas tarefas é denominado ***Protocolos elementares de enlace de dados.***
E o código do protocolo é por sua vez um conjunto de classes.

Algumas definições utilizadas nos protocolos apresentados são armazenadas no arquivo ***protocol.h***

```
#define MAX_PKT 1024  // Packet size in bytes
typedef enum {false,true} boolean;
typedef unsigned int seq_nr // seq or ack numbers
typedef struct {unsigned char data[MAX_PKT];} packet
typedef enum {data, ack,nak} frame_kind

typedef struct{
  frame_kind kind;
  seq_nr seq;
  seq_nr ack;
  packet info;
} frame;

void waif_for_event(event_type *event);
void from_network_layer(packet *p);
void to_network_layer(packet *p);
void from_physical_layer(frame *r);
void to_physical_layer(frame *s);
void start_timer(seq_nr k);
void stop_timer(seq_nr k);
void start_ack_timer(void);
void stop_ack_timer(void);
void enable_network_layer(void);
void disalbe_network_layer(void);
insira o código aqui
#define inc(k) if(k<MAX_SEQ) k++; else k=0
```

***Exemplos de protocolos e códigos***

- ***[Protocolo simplex para canal com ruído](http://ftp.utcluj.ro/pub/docs/laboratoare/RET/cn3-simulator/p3.c)***
- ***[Protocolo de janela deslizante que utiliza go back n](http://ftp.utcluj.ro/pub/docs/laboratoare/RET/cn3-simulator/p4.c)***
- ***[Protocolo de repetição seletiva](http://ftp.utcluj.ro/pub/docs/laboratoare/RET/cn3-simulator/p5.c)***

***Pipelining e recuperação de erros. Efeito de um erro quando (a) o tamanho da janela receptora é igual a 1 e quando (b) o tamanho da janela receptora é grande***

[image: Pipe]

Nota sobre esclarecimento:

Na pratica esses protocolos são utilizados de forma embutida nos hardwares responsáveis pela transmissão e recepção dos dados, e são
abstraídos das camadas mais próximas do usuário final, por isso passa desapercebido.

Agradecimento especial a [Tanenbaum](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Stuart_Tanenbaum)

Comment: Desculpe não ter respondido antes, mas deixei meu último comentário pouco antes de dormir e não pude responder apropriadamente. Por favor não leve pro lado pessoal. Vamos lá: 1) Lamento se minha pergunta não foi clara. Me referia especificamente ao *forward error correction*, tal como linkado pra Wikipedia, e não tenho interesse [nessa pergunta específica] em ARQ. Comentei "noto que na prática se é erro de comunicação, retransmite" e achei que tinha deixado claro que a pergunta não era sobre esse tipo de técnica. Vou tentar me comunicar melhor da próxima vez.

Comment: 2) Sua resposta original - citando e explicando a distância de Hamming e coisas assim - de fato foi muito relevante e direto no ponto que eu queria. Mas ainda assim, era cópia de conteúdo protegido, e isso é sério. Deixei aquele comentário justamente pra te dar a oportunidade de corrigir o problema você mesmo, antes de notificar à moderação, mas dado o momento que isso aconteceu (1:30 da madrugada no meu fuso horário) não tive como elaborar mais. Agradeço o esforço de pesquisa, e acho que o material citado é uma excelente referência (como link, não como cópia).

Comment: Eu vou dar uma lida mais com calma, depois te dou um feedback. Se a técnica de hamming é suficiente ou não, eu não sei, se eu soubesse exatamente qual é a resposta "certa" eu não precisaria ter feito a pergunta rsrs! Por isso preciso da opinião de pessoas mais experientes que eu. Pelo que eu entendi até agora, boa parte do que foi perguntado essa técnica responde (quase tudo que perguntei nos primeiros 2 itens). Somente quanto à parte prática que continuo no escuro (pois pelo que entendi da sua resposta até agora, na prática isso é usado em escala mínima, dando prioridade ao ARQ).

Comment: E já que você está pedindo opiniões pra aprimorar sua resposta, o que eu penso é o seguinte: apenas citar a técnica não é o suficiente, o ideal seria que ela fosse brevemente explicada ("fico satisfeito com apenas uma introdução seguida de algumas referências") e que pelo menos alguns dos pontos perguntados fossem diretamente abordados (Ex.: "esses códigos corrigem erros em posições arbitrárias nos dados (...) ou só alguns tipos de erro específicos? É possível o código "corrigir" pra algo diferente dos dados originais?" etc), não necessariamente todos, é claro, fica a seu critério.

Comment: Sem problemas! Se alguém se dispuser a dar uma resposta mais didática, isso será priorizado, do contrário não terei problemas em aceitar sua resposta (afinal no SOpt cada um contribui na medida que pode e quer, e toda contribuição é válida).

Comment: "Didática" é só uma das qualidades que uma resposta por ter, não necessariamente a melhor. Um manual de operações não é didático, um tutorial sim. Às vezes você precisa de um, às vezes de outro. Dito isso, vou parar por aqui, antes que isso se transforme num bate-boca...

Comment: @MagicHat acho desnecessário [comentários como este](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71515/o-que-s%c3%a3o-c%c3%b3digos-corretores-de-erros/134461#comment278712_134481) a explicar o que didática é depois de já ter sido referido o que falta na resposta. Se deres uma olhada às respostas do mgibsonbr vais vêr que são didáticas e bem explicativas. Acho que, neste caso, se ele comenta que faltam coisas na resposta é de aproveitar e aprender com isso. Não é todos os dias que temos alguém bem experiente a sugerir melhorias no que fazemos. É assim que nos melhoramos, com desafios.

Comment: Agora que a poeira baixou, deixe-me tentar de novo: quando um usuário faz uma pergunta, é prerrogativa dele qual resposta aceitar, ou nenhuma, se não estiver satisfeito. Idem pra quem concede uma recompensa. Os votos, por outro lado, são um reflexo da comunidade, e se sua resposta está sendo bem recebida pela mesma - como a sua está - é isso que realmente importa, não a opinião de um usuário particular como eu. Por fim, citando a Central de Ajuda, 'se a sua motivação for “eu gostaria que outros me expliquem ______”, provavelmente está no lugar certo'. Se alguém se dispuser, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: Do contrário, sugiro que mantenha sua resposta como está, não há necessidade de qualquer alteração (exceto um pequeno detalhe que eu mesmo sugerirei, favor reverter se não concordar com a edição). É uma boa resposta, bem abrangente, cujo escopo ainda extrapola o que foi pedido. O que é bom: a política do Stack Overflow é evitar jogar fora boas respostas, por isso seria uma pena que sua excelente resposta fosse alterada em demasia por conta de um "capricho" meu. E você sempre tem a opção de dar mais de uma resposta, se assim o desejar (e se não, suas contribuições já são mais que suficientes).

Comment: P.S. Eu vi suas últimas alterações, abordando mais o que foi pedido. Tem meu *upvote*, +1.